# Not shutting down: CPU soft lockup (plymouthd) / self-detected stall on CPU

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, cpu, plymouth, lockup

When I click <kbd>Shut down</kbd> in the system menu, it does not turn off but repeatedly shows the errors below.

```
MMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:4693]
INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
```

[image]

I have to turn the computer off forcefully by holding the power button.